# Why nodemailer give me this error when I try to send an e-mail using gmail address? Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am working on a Firebase project that uses Google Cloud Functions. I am some problem trying to implement a cloud function that uses **nodemailer** in order to send an e-mail.

I have something like this in my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

import nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp();

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'my-sender-mail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'my-password'
    }
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `my-sender-mail@gmail.com`,
    to: `my-destination-mail@gmail.com`,
    subject: 'contact form message',
    text: 'TEST TEST TEST'
    /*
    html: `<h1>Order Confirmation</h1>
     <p> <b>Email: </b>TEST </p>`
     */
  };

  export const sendEmailNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log("sendEmailNotification START 2");

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          response.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR SENDING MAIL !!!'});
      }
      console.log("Sent!");
      response.status(200).json({message: 'NOTIFICATION MAIL SENT !!!'});
    });

  });
```

So as you can see I prepared the **transporter** object setting the gmail confifuration inserting user and password as authentication.

Then the **maulOption** object contains the e-mail to be sent.

Finnally I defined a GET function that called should send the e-mail.

The problem is that it is not working and I am obtaining the following error into the Firebase cloud function log:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at transporter.sendMail (/srv/lib/index.js:72:30)
    at transporter.send.args (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:226:21)
    at connection.login.err (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:282:36)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1513:20)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:540:26)
```

What it means? What is wrong? What am I missing? I am going crazy...how can I fix my code in order to correctly send this e-mail?

**EDIT-1:** After that I solved the header error I am obtaining this new error message:

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t12sm13191635ios.12 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1513:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:540:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:932:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:739:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:189:44)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t12sm13191635ios.12 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

**EDIT-2**: As suggested I actevated also the **Less secure app access** but now I obtain this error message into the Firebase cloud function log:

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs
534-5.7.14 XR1smQTqgOc7rRSUWEDTn9TfUIueWg5Fyd78-WkCR0YjjNDoMp91N1f4Lwy0EE9YKy720
534-5.7.14 Eg9dGeLWkuox0l8KKoOB2GdveIVKleuQ7mO5oYJT6ZMLdk-EzDxujYyknc_YmpkV>
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m26sm16711541ill.21 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1513:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:540:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:932:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:739:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (/srv/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:189:44)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs\n534-5.7.14 XR1smQTqgOc7rRSUWEDTn9TfUIueWg5Fyd78-WkCR0YjjNDoMp91N1f4Lwy0EE9YKy720\n534-5.7.14 Eg9dGeLWkuox0l8KKoOB2GdveIVKleuQ7mO5oYJT6ZMLdk-EzDxujYyknc_YmpkV>\n534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n534-5.7.14  Learn more at\n534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m26sm16711541ill.21 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 534,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

Comment: When you encounter a new problem, it's customary to post a new question for that rather than layering them all into the same question.  When you move the goalposts by asking new questions on top of old question, it confuses the existing answers that were helpful for the first problem.  In order to be helpful for others in the future, I suggest revering the question to just your original problem, accepting the correct answer for that, and posting the second issue separately.

Answer (score 1):

The fix should be pretty simple; At the moment, you're setting the response status twice, this is what is causing the issue in the logs.

Changing the transporter.sendMail callback like to should fix this:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR SENDING MAIL !!!'});
  } else { 
      console.log("Sent!");
      response.status(200).json({message: 'NOTIFICATION MAIL SENT !!!'});
  }
});
```

I suspect there's another error sending the mail as well, but it won't be logged until you're able to fix this one.

I believe you'll also need to configure the gmail account to accept logins from nodemailer.

Comment: Yes, the header problem is not solved but now I am obtaining a new error that I put at the end of my original post

Comment: Great! At least that's one step further! I'll see what I can do about the other error

Comment: Is the gmail account configured for less secure app access: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4MgVj3uXSkZcOyz9wAm34Fvm6Wc316uBa1NEBiwlFm9R9GXFouWjn_QXF0t5xTqOrQkgllvo5ssisBqRYDZt8IwPJ-W7Q

Comment: Done, but now I obtain a new error that I put in the **EDIT-2** section at the endo of my original post

Comment: Is two factor authentication enabled for the google account?

Comment: Do you mean the telephone message one? No I enter onlu with username and password on my Google account

Comment: I'd suggest adding an app password: https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords and using this to send the mail using Nodemailer, this is working for me. NB: I'm using 2FA, but I think this is much more secure in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

If your account is using 2FA, then you need to use app password, instead of your regular password you use on web. You can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).

There might be another way to give access by enabling **less secure apps** but as name suggest it is not recommended, but for testing purposes you can try to enable it. Read more about it [here](https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=68108&sliceId=1#:%7E:text=If%20getting%20%22Username%20and%20Password,authentication%20in%20your%20email%20settings.).

**EDIT**

You might also need to Unlock Captcha in order to gain access. Try this [link](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha).

Comment: Done, but now I obtain a new error that I put in the **EDIT-2** section at the endo of my original post